# Firebase instance id: deprecation of getId() in 21.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

With the recent release of FirebaseInstanceId and FirebaseCloudMessaging (`21.0.0`) Firebase has deprecated `iid` package and both `getToken()` and `getId()` methods are now deprecated.

According to the [**Firebase release note**](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#iid_v21-0-0) the method `getToken()` is moved to `FirebaseMessaging`

Before:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()
```

After:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()
```

Which gives use the `fcmToken`, but to retrieve **instance id**, there's no method available in FirebaseMessaging nor FirebaseInstanceId.

---

**So**, Is `instance_id` considered a useless id and should no longer be used? or is there a replacement for this?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

FirebaseInstanceId class is deprecated, to get token use FirebaseMessagingClass. The token can be generated using the following code:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()
.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
      if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Fetching FCM registration token failed", task.getException());
        return;
      }

      // Get new FCM registration token
      String token = task.getResult();

      // Log and toast
      String msg = getString(R.string.msg_token_fmt, token);
      Log.d(TAG, msg);
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Regarding the Firebase InstanceId, this is what the official document says:

> public Task getInstanceId () ->
> This method is deprecated.
> For an instance identifier, use FirebaseInstallations.getId() instead. For an FCM registration token, use FirebaseMessaging.getToken() instead.

Comment: Since your answer has gotten the most votes so far, it's better to accept this one. Cheers

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a FirebaseInstallations package for C#, am I mistaken?

Comment: This one is for Android

Answer (score 10):

### Fcm Token

**Before deprecation**

```
val fcmToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()
```

**Replacement**

```
val fcmToken = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()
```

---

### `FirebaseInstanceId#getId`

**Before deprecation**

```
val istanceId = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getId()
```

**Replacement**

Checking out the code of `FirebaseInstanceId#getId()` I saw the suggestion that you should use `FirebaseInstallations#getId` instead.

> This method is deprecated
>
> Use `FirebaseInstallations.getId()` instead.

```
val instanceId = FirebaseInstallation.getInstance().getId()
```

Comment: Note that this may not return the same thing. FirebaseInstallation instanceId is not the one that's meant to be used for FCM

Comment: FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken() gave me the same result as the deprecated  FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()

Comment: That is `fcmToken`. The question is about instanceId and not token. InstanceId can be achieved using `FirebaseInstanceId#getId()` method.

Answer (score 4):

- ##### FCM Token:

  Use [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) package

  ```dart
  String? token = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
  ```
- ##### Installation ID:

  Use [flutterfire_installations](https://pub.dev/packages/flutterfire_installations) package

  ```dart
  String id = await FirebaseInstallations.instance.getId();
  ```
- ##### Installation auth token:

  ```dart
  String token = await FirebaseInstallations.instance.getToken();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
 public String getToken() {
String token;
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                           token = task.getResult();
                            

                        }
                    }
                });
        
        return token;
    }
```

Comment: This'll return FCM token which is the `result.token` of `iid.getToken()`. There is a `FirebaseInstanceId.id` which is now achieved by `FIS.getId()` according to the accepted answer