# 'com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId' is deprecated

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was using the following to get FCM token and send it to Firebase realtime database.

```
   FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {

            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                String token = task.getResult().getToken();
                if (mUser != null) {
                    databaseReference.child("Tokens").child(mUser.getUid()).setValue(token);
                }

            }

        }
    });
```

No, since FirebaseInstanceId is deprecated so I am getting a deprecation warning in Android Studio. What is the replacement?

Comment: "In favour of overriding onNewToken in FirebaseMessagingService. Once that has been implemented, this service can be safely removed." from [Firebase Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51125169/what-to-use-now-that-firebaseinstanceid-getinstance-gettoken-is-deprecated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573538/firebase-instance-id-deprecation-of-getid-in-21-0-0